# HttpClient PostAsync A task was cancelled

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, task

I'm trying to perform a POST HTTP request on a certain URL, on my client's (business client) server.
It works for him.
I'm using the HttpClient class like this :

```
message = await client.PostAsync(formattedUrl, content, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The timeout property is set o default (140 sec), but PostAsync throws an exception immediately, that's why I think there is no timeout problem.

My header is simple : a ContentType set to application/json
a ContentLength, and my body has one field.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. My simple HttpClient immedialty throwing that exception. Did you find a solution or some hint to the cause of this?

Comment: Check your URL, if I remember (it was last year in a different company) I had an issue with it